# SwiftUI expanding list animation broken on iOS 16.4

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, ios16.4

I have a SwiftUI expanding list built as shown in this [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-expanding-lists).

Here is my implementation:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var movies: [Movie]

    var body: some View {
        List(movies, children: \.movies) { movie in
                Text(movie.title)
        }
    }
}

struct Movie: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    var movies: [Movie]?
}
```

Here is the animation on iOS 16.1:

[image: List on iOS 16.1]

And Since **iOS 16.4** the animation is broken:

[image: List on iOS 16.4]

Is it a bug on OS level or should I use another technique ?

Comment: I had exactly same problem in my app from iOS 16.4. i tried couple of other approaches for animation but nothing worked. Please let me know if you find anything for this issue.

Comment: Hey! Did you report this bug?

Comment: Hello Alexander. Yes I did just now

Comment: exact same issue in iOS 17.  Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 4):

I have to close `List` second-level animation for iOS 16.4 with this bug.

```
List{}.transaction { transaction in
    transaction.animation = nil
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this just removes the transition altogether rather than having the default normal behavior in 16.1 shown in the question that list has always had.